# TDS Hedgehog Sync Project with Sitecore popup only shows an empty frame

Tags: visual-studio, sitecore, sitecore8, tds

I am installing a Sitecore 8.2 solution and setting up the environment. I am using TDS Hedgehog 5.8.0.6. I came across a weird error that none of my coworkers had: when I tried to sync a content project with Sitecore (by context clicking the menu item "Sync Project with Sitecore" from a content project), I get a popup in Visual Studio 2019 with only the title bar, close, expand, and dock buttons, and the empty frame. Nothing shows up in the window no matter how long I keep it open.

I have restarted my machine, restarted Visual Studio, have reinstalled the TDS extension, already built the projects (we have a specific order for our solution and specific projects to build), and have tested the TDS connection through the Build tab of the Properties window of the projects. All the projects do this. I did install the TDS for Sitecore 8.2 and Visual Studio Professional 2019. There are no logs in the output window or errors or warnings in the error window.

[image: SYnc with Sitecore does not show up byt Get Sitecore Items does]

Has anyone else seen this in Visual Studio? Anyone have a solution?

EDIT: I have found some warnings in the ActivityLog.Setup.xml if this helps.

```
<entry>
    <record>42</record>
    <time>2019/10/10 00:17:05.020</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef encountered data collision in section &apos;HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_bc996d64_Config_15432\ToolsOptionsPages\TDS Options&apos; for value &apos;&apos;</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>43</record>
    <time>2019/10/10 00:17:05.021</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef encountered data collision in section &apos;HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_bc996d64_Config_15432\ToolsOptionsPages\TDS Options&apos; for value &apos;Package&apos;</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>44</record>
    <time>2019/10/10 00:17:05.022</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef encountered data collision in section &apos;HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_bc996d64_Config_15432\ToolsOptionsPages\TDS Options&apos; for value &apos;&apos;</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>45</record>
    <time>2019/10/10 00:17:05.022</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef encountered data collision in section &apos;HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_bc996d64_Config_15432\ToolsOptionsPages\TDS Options&apos; for value &apos;Package&apos;</description>
  </entry>
```

I notice the registry keys that are colliding do not exist in my registry so it appears those are not being written to. I have no idea why.
...

```
<entry>
    <record>2805</record>
    <time>2019/10/10 00:17:35.347</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>Project Template Metadata</source>
    <description>No template metadata found for ID: COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\2ZS02JOD.H1B\ProjectTemplates\TDS Project With Wizard\TDS Project with Wizard.vstemplate</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2806</record>
    <time>2019/10/10 00:17:35.347</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>Project Template Metadata</source>
    <description>No template metadata found for ID: COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\2ZS02JOD.H1B\ProjectTemplates\TDS Project\TDS Project.vstemplate</description>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had to upgrade from 5.8.0.6 to most recent version of TDS Hedgehog connector (6.0.0.8) to get this working. When in doubt, do an update.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me, in Visual Studio, go to:

1. Tools
2. Options
3. In Enviroment/General, make sure to uncheck the following: "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities (requires restart)"

Comment: This worked for an older version of TDS than the latest.